# Autorelease pools in appkit applications

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, autorelease, appkit

I'm having difficulties to understand exactly WHEN autorelease pools are created and released in AppKit apps.

For example, if I have an ApplicationController class that overrides init, is there an autorelease pool that gets created before it starts and gets drained after it ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread in an AppKit application runs an NSRunLoop to process events. NSRunLoop creates a new autorelease pool every time it processes a new event (or timer) and drains it once control flow has returned to the NSRunLoop. So in essence, every pass through the run loop has a fresh autorelease pool.

Comment: So when will objects created in init be released? O:-)

Comment: Once you've started the runloop, if you autorelease anything, it will get released once control flow returns to the runloop. The only exceptions are if you autorelease something inside of `main()` (which is outside of the run loop) or in another thread.

Comment: Fernando: They will be released when they are released. Objects you add to an autorelease pool are released when the pool drains. A pool you create drains when you drain it; a pool created by the run loop drains when… well, the answer tells you that.